# Reading out a chat log using Selenium for Python 2.7

Tags: python, selenium, skype

Okay. So basicly I am trying to write a bot for our Skype Group Chat. Skype switched from p2p Group chats to Cloud Based chats so using Skype4Py is no longer possible unless you change it back to p2p. Skype has a webclient tho which I want to use for the bot. This far I managed to write a really basic script using selenium which is able to open FireFox and open the WebClient aswell as Logging in and Sendind Messages. I now need to figure out a way to always analazye the newest message of said GroupChat for Commands and KeyPhrases.

My Code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://web.skype.com/en/')
time.sleep(8)
login_name = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
login_name.send_keys('---------')
login_password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
login_password.send_keys('----------' + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(8)
input_messages = browser.find_element_by_name('messageInput')
input_messages.send_keys('Testing Output' + Keys.RETURN)
```

The thing is I can't really figure out how to access the newest message. I tried to use the firefox development tool to figure out the name of the variable where the newest message is saved but I was not succesfull so far. Any help is appreciated

Edit: I figured out the right class I think. It looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8QNG.jpg

The role'log' always tells you when there is a new message and what user send it. It also shows the message itself. I just need a way to Analyze that String with Selenium